# Clojure interop for Scala objects and traits

Tags: scala, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I am trying to use a Scala library in a Clojure project but running into some issues.  How would you implement the following Scala code in Clojure?

```
object LabelDomain extends CategoricalDomain[String]
class Label(val token: Token, s: String) extends LabeledCategoricalVariable(s) {
  def domain = LabelDomain
}

object FeaturesDomain extends CategoricalDimensionTensorDomain[String]
class Features(val token: Token) extends BinaryFeatureVectorVariable[String] {
  def domain = FeaturesDomain
}

object model extends ChainModel[Label,  Features, Token](
      LabelDomain,
      FeaturesDomain,
      l => l.token.attr[Features],
      l => l.token,
      t => t.attr[Label])
```

`CategoricalDomain` and `CategoricalDimensionTensorDomain` are traits.
`LabeledCategoricalVariable` and `BinaryFeatureVectorVariable` are abstract classes.
`ChainModel` is a class.

Comment: I have to wonder how good a match Scala is for Clojure from a library interoperability perspective. Also… I think you need to say a bit more about the various defined names in your example—it's pretty sparse.

Comment: @RandallSchulz I have updated the post to be more specific about the types involved.

Comment: Perhaps the question can be drastically simplified? The terminology ('categorical', '[tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor)', 'domain', etc) might be scaring people away, even though they have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Heavy OO code is not a good match for Clojure (it's still doable, of course), maybe you should do it in Scala. Clojure is more about data while Scala is more about types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use [FACTORIE](http://factorie.cs.umass.edu/) with clojure. As someone who both loves clojure and works at the lab that builds FACTORIE, I wouldn't recommend this. FACTORIE's codebase is written in a very imperative style, and is filled with mutable state. If I got my hands on a FACTORIE object in clojure I would find it very disorienting. FACTORIE also makes aggressive use of scala features in ways that won't translate well to compiled java (which is the level at which clojure and scala must interact).

If you already have a large clojure codebase and need a good implementation of a linear-chain CRF (based on your use of `ChainModel` above), I'd recommend looking at [MALLET](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/). It's pure java and was developed by the same lab.